# a is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I didn't define `a`, but when I run the code, it prompts me

> a is not a function at
> var dataset = l5_sr.filterDate (startDate, endDate)’.

Here is my code

```
   function rml457Cloude(image){
     
     var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
     var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5));
     var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
     var mask3 =image.select('B1').gt(2000);
     
     return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2).updateMask(mask3.not())
                 .copyProperties(image)
                 .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start",'system:time_end','system:footprint'])
   }
   
   var l5_sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                 .map(rml457Cloude)
                 .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',5));  
   
   var Landsat57 ={
     scaleimage: function (image){
       var time_start = image.get('system:time_start');
       image = image.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7']);
       image = image.set('system:time_start',time_start);
     },
     //SR  remove cloud 
     srCloudMask: function(image) {
     var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
     var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
     var snowBitMask = ( 1 << 4);
     var cloudBitMask = (1 <<5);
     var mask1 = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                   .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0))
                   .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0));
     var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
     return image.updateMask(mask1.and(mask2));
     },
     //NDVI
     NDVI:function(image){
       return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']).rename('NDVI'));
     },
     //MNDWI
     MNDWI: function(image){
       return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B5']).rename('MNDWI'));
     },
     //EVI
     EVI: function(image){
      var evi =image.expression('EVI =2.5*(NIR-R)/(NIR+6*R-7.5*B+1)',{
        NIR: image.select('B4'),
        R: image.select('B3'),
        B: image.select('B1')
      });
      return image.addBands(evi);
     },
     //water dataset
     getL5SRCollection : function(startDate, endDate, region){
       var dataset = l5_sr.filterDate (startDate, endDate)//Here's the Error
                          .filterBounds(region)
                          .map(Landsat57.srCloudMask)
                          .map(Landsat57.scaleImage)
                          .map(Landsat57.NDVI)
                          .map(Landsat57.MNDVI)
                          .map(Landsat57.EVI)
                          .map(calcwater)
                          .select('water');
       return dataset;
     },
     getL7SRCollection : function(startDate, endDate, region){
       var dataset2 = l7_sr.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                          .filterBounds(region)
                          .map(Landsat57.srCloudMask)
                          .map(Landsat57.scaleImage)
                          .map(Landsat57.NDVI)
                          .map(Landsat57.MNDVI)
                          .map(Landsat57.EVI)
                          .map(calcwater)
                          .select('water');
       return dataset
     },
   };
```

Why I am getting this error in my code?

Comment: One of the libraries you're using probably defines that function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056253/why-is-my-javascript-function-a-not-defined may help

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any output, so running it does not reproduce the error. Also, you code example would benefit from simplification... keep removing parts until you cannot reproduce the error.